# Template vs templateUrl AND styles vs styleUrls - Performance

Tags: javascript, performance, angular

In Angular 2, we can either use inline or url approach for templates and styles. Using url is good for modularity, readability and IDEs also provide code assistance. Using url will result in additional request from browser which might cause some performance drop. What's the recommended way of using templates and style - either inline or url?

Example from [Angular 2 cheatsheet](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html)

```
template: 'Hello {{name}}'
templateUrl: 'my-component.html'    

styles: ['.primary {color: red}']
styleUrls: ['my-component.css']
```

Comment: The Angular team is working on an offline compiler and there are also Gulp tasks that inline templates before deployment, therefore there is no performance penalty in production. Therefore only consider what @PardeepJain wrote to decide whether templates should be inlined or not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes well said

> Using url is good for modularity, readability and IDEs also provide code assistance. Using url will result in additional request from browser which might cause some performance drop

but its depends on us how long our code is according to @mgchev style guide

> Extract the more complex and bigger templates, longer than 15 lines of code, into a separate file and put them next to their controllers' definition.
>
> Why?: In case a big and complex template is inlined in the component metadata it may shift the focus from the component's logic defined within the controller.

but if we look at the officials style guide than it will tell us to use seprate file if coding exceeds more than 3 lines

> Do extract templates and styles into a separate file, when more than 3 lines.

also same case apply's in the Css styles, so better is to provide exteranal url instead of inline if we have complex code.
also see here :

- https://mgechev.github.io/angular2-style-guide/
- https://angular.io/styleguide